# How to multiply all the values of a column?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've a DataGridView like this layout:

[image]

I would like to find a way to multiply all values of the column "Quota", in particular, I wrote a code like this:

```
    If MetroGrid1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If MetroGrid1.Columns.Contains("Quota") Then
            Dim CostTotal As Decimal = MetroGrid1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow) _
                                       .Select(
                                        Function(x)
                                            Return CDec(x.Cells("Quota").Value)
                                        End Function
            ).Sum
            Dim risultato = CostTotal * giocata
```

The problem is that the only mode available is the sum and average, but there is no multiplication. I would like to find a way to replace `.Sum` with some command that allows me to multiply or totally change the algorithm if necessary.

Comment: If you want to multiply every cell under a column it will yield different results and im not sure if this is your intention.

Comment: A practical example, the image I have in the column "Quota": 2.7 and 2.4, then the result you will get will be: 6:48, here is what I want to do.

Comment: Declare a double variable then take this total and when you loop through multiply the next value against it and continue through your loop...

Comment: Your can do a next loop for this.

Comment: And select must be removed? Can you show me an example, please?

Comment: Yes select can be removed and replaced with below example.

Comment: Also in your image you provided that column has commas separating the values, not doubles or integers or decimals. Not sure if this was a typo?

Comment: The grid has commas in the cells...not periods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65905/discussion-between-heisenberg-and-mr-codexer).

Comment: Don't manipulate data grid directly, use a business object assigned via DataSource property. You will find that syntax is much easier to write and understand this way.

Answer (score 0):

To multiply every cell as you go through the grid you can loop through multiplying the values and adding it to a variable... First we'll make sure there is a value and if so lets try and cast that value as a double. If so multiply the old values with the new one and so on...

```
 Dim dblTotal As Double = 0
 Dim dblValue As Double = 0


 For i As Integer = 0 To MetroGrid1.Rows.Count - 1
    If MetroGrid1.Rows(i).Cells("Quota").Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
     If Double.TryParse(MetroGrid1.Rows(i).Cells("Quota").Value.ToString, dblValue) Then
      dblTotal *= dblValue
     End If
    End If

 Next
```

Comment: I add this code but the "Quota" column values are replace with 0, why?

Comment: I told you above, you have commas separating the values not periods. Therefore they are not doubles but strings...

Comment: Something like .Value.ToString.Split(","c)?