# CDec doesn't return the correct value

Tags: vb.net

I make code that multiply all values of a DatagridView column. The code is working, but there's a problem. In particular, I've added this:

```
Return CDec(x.Cells("Quote").Value.ToString.Replace(",", "."))
```

That returns me the split value, for example, if I would have:

2,7 the correct value to return is: 2.7, but the code returns 27 and this is strange. I performed some trying, and if I delete the CDec like:

```
Return x.Cells("Quote").Value.ToString.Replace(",", ".")
```

The value returned is correct, but I've a contrast with this function:

```
Private Function MultiplyDecimals(ByVal sender As Decimal()) As Decimal
    Dim Result As Decimal
    If Not sender Is Nothing AndAlso Not sender.Length = 0 Then
        Result = sender.Aggregate(Function(a, b) a * b)
    End If
    Return Result
End Function
```

That returns me 0 if I delete "As Decimal". So what's wrong?

UPDATE with possible solution:

```
Dim bles = x.Cells("Quote").Value.ToString.Replace(",", ".")
                            Dim key = Convert.ToDecimal(bles)
                            MessageBox.Show(key)
                            Return CDec(key)
```

Comment: CDec is taking integer as parameter? and you are passing string. So parse in Decimal first then use Cdec

Comment: are you trying to convert/import a value from a different language (Is that the purpose of the `Replace(",", ".")`)?

Comment: Yes the value is with comma. I've update the question with a possible fix of @Piyush, but it doesn't working. Return me the value without the comma.

Comment: ok, so what language is the source in?

Comment: Is a simple table like: http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/4d1e/2zmdi9jocora6tqfg.jpg

Comment: that does not answer the question...NET has built in methods to do what you want.  we just need the specifics.

Comment: What's the source of the data for the DataGridView? How do you fill it? Manually? What's the culture configuration of your PC? I think the problem is that, for whatever reason, "." is the thousands separator and thus converting the value to decimal takes it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it *looks like* you are also trying to manually convert from a different culture, you should use the .NET methods for this, rather than roll your own. You have two conversions going on: From one cultural number system to another and from string to a numeric type.

To convert a string like "2,7" which *might* be a French or Italian value:

```
Dim str As String = "2,7"

Dim decVal As Decimal
If Decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
        New CultureInfo("it-IT"), decVal) Then
   ' decVal has the value
Else
   ' Parse failed
End If
```

or:

```
Dim cult As New CultureInfo("fr-FR")
If Decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
           cult, decVal) Then ...
```

This can often work, but you might get an exception depending on the content:

```
Dim decVal As Decimal
Dim cult As New CultureInfo("fr-FR")
decVal = Convert.ToDecimal(str, cult)

Console.WriteLine(decVal.ToString)
```

Note: I am guessing at the culture of the data. Based on your [recent, related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27213970/1070452) Google indicates "Nazione" is Italian, but data from/about Algeria might well be French Algerian.

---

`CDec`, like most of the legacy VB functions, is only equipped to work with the active culture settings. So, it will seem like it is "broken" in some cases:

```
Console.WriteLine(CDec("2.7"))           ' --> 2.7D   US/Can
Console.WriteLine(CDec("2,7"))           ' --> 27D
Console.WriteLine(CDec("2,,7"))          ' --> 27D
```

On a machine using French or Italian culture, the opposite will happen: "2.7" will come out 27, "2,7" to 2.7D, but "2,,7" will probably crash just like "2..7" would in the US/Can.

The reason for this behavior is that in US/Can, a comma looks like noise and `CDec` ignores it. A string with a single decimal-dot will convert, but a string with 2 is invalid. It would be the reverse for French where the comma is used: any number of dots look like noise, and only single decimal-comma format will parse.

It is all part of the reason no one included `CDec` in the solution: It is sub-optimal for any sort of cultural conversions. Manually removing or replacing decimal markers is even *less* optimal when there are methods designed to do that only when needed.

Comment: Now i inserted: MessageBox.Show(CDec(x.Cells("Quote").Value.ToString.Replace(",", ".")))
and I will return the value attached as I said earlier, while if I instead of "." I post whatever I replaced properly. The problem is right here.

Comment: I found the problem. Is CDec that remove the "."

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a string value, try [`Decimal.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx) instead of CDec().

If that doesn't give you the result you expect, then either you're not handling the string that you think you are (in which case, try logging the exact string to a text file or similar so you can see exactly what you have), or the PC's culture settings are not what you think they are (it may be set to a culture that uses the comma, rather than a period, as the decimal separator), in which case try one of the Decimal.Parse() overloads that allows you to specify the culture, or perhaps even just remove the call to `.Replace()`.

Comment: I don't think that comment was there when I loaded the question, but if Decimal.Parse is not giving you the correct value, you're either not parsing the string that you think you are, or the culture settings on the computer are not what you think they are. I'll edit that last part into my answer.

Comment: It's as if the comma instead of being replaced by the point is eliminated, and so if I have: 2.27 I find: 227